# Alter table and Create 40+ Column in existing table in single script

Tags: sql-server

On an existing table, I want to add 47 columns using `alter table` script

```
select Distinct FieldName From customFields
```

Above query will list 47 rows and these row names I need to create in another table (table name is Equipment) as Column.

I am using MS SQL 2017. Please help.

Comment: Do you mean create another table dynamically with column names based on the values of `FieldName`? Are all the data types the same?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are storing the name of these columns in this table `customFields` and you want them all to be `int`:

```
DECLARE @cmd nvarchar(max) = N'ALTER TABLE dbo.Equipment ADD $ int;',
        @sql nvarchar(max) = N'';

SELECT @sql += CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + REPLACE(@cmd, N'$', QUOTENAME(FieldName))
  FROM dbo.customFields
  GROUP BY FieldName;

PRINT @sql;
-- EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
```

Note that printing the output to check it might not show the entire script because SSMS limits its output by default. For workarounds see [this tip](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3185/validate-the-contents-of-large-dynamic-sql-strings-in-sql-server/).

If what you **actually** mean is you want to create an exact copy of `customFields`, you can do that much simpler:

```
SELECT * INTO dbo.Equipment FROM dbo.customFields;
```

There are some exceptions, like if you have computed columns, don't want the IDENTITY property copied, etc. but this should cover a lot of cases. If you have a particular use case, please make your question more specific.

Answer (score 1):

If they have different data types, you can build it from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS

Something like the following (bare bones, edit as needed for your needs and data types)

```
SELECT 'ALTER TABLE Equipment ADD ' + column_name + ' ' + 
       CASE WHEN data_type IN ('varchar', 'char') THEN data_type + '(' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), character_maximum_length) + ') '
            ELSE data_type END AS [new_field]
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE table_name = 'customFields'
ORDER BY ordinal_position
```

Comment: I think the names of the new columns are stored as values in the column `FieldName`, not as columns in the table.